# ASP.NET MVC3 EditorTemplates and Name Attributes

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, razor, jquery-validate, mvc-editor-templates

I am using editor templates in my code and what I noticed is that lot of the controls get the name property set based on index.

```
@Html.EditorFor(x => x.Emails)
```

Where Answers is collection of EmailViewModel object

What gets rendered is this for each of item:

```
<input data-val="true" data-val-number="The field must be a number." 
      data-val-required="The Email field is required." 
      id="Emails_0__EmailId" name="Emails[0].EmailId" value="1">
```

I tried to set the name property like this:

```
@Html.TextBoxFor(x => x.EmailId, new { @name = "EmailAdress" })
```

But this has no effect!

What do I need to do so it takes name value in effect. The main reason for doing this is for validation purposes. In my validation rules I have the following:

```
$("#someForm").validate({
        rules: {
            EmailAddress: {
                required: true,
                email: true
            }
        }
    });
```

Comment: Is x.Emails a List or Array? You shouldn't use EditorFor()  to a list of objects unless you create your own Editor template with the correct handling to the list objects

Comment: It names them this way so the model binder can bind to a collection properly. If you change this you will have to do some additional work to make sure that everything binds correctly when you post the form.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try

```
@Html.EditorFor(x => x.Emails, "string", "EmailAddress") //or EmailAdress
```

[MSDN reference](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee407399%28v=vs.108%29.aspx) has the following, you are interested in the `htmlFieldName`

```
public static MvcHtmlString EditorFor<TModel, TValue>(
    this HtmlHelper<TModel> html,
    Expression<Func<TModel, TValue>> expression,
    string templateName,
    string htmlFieldName
)
```

*A string that is used to disambiguate the names of HTML input elements that are rendered for properties that have the same name.*

To edit the prefix you can set this in your controller

```
ViewData.TemplateInfo.HtmlFieldPrefix
```

or in your view

```
@Html.ViewContext.ViewData.TemplateInfo.HtmlFieldPrefix = "Foo"
```

Of course you could write your own helper that does this wherever you use it.

Comment: still adds this: [0].EmailAddress as name

Comment: Where would this go in the controller?